# Как сжимать данные по AJAX запросу?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Получаю данные по `ajax` в виде `json`, проблема  в том что данные весят сумарно от 10 до 45 мегабайт, что постоянно гонять такой объем мягко говоря не очень.

Как получать данные в сжатом виде, а на стороне клиента в браузере эти данные приводить в исходный вид и делать дальнейшую обработку?

Если эти данные сжимать обычным `zip` архиватором, то размер всего 40-150 килобайт, но как это через ajax реализовать?

```
// PHP

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

```js
function getData() {
  fetch('/terminal')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Нормальный веб-сервер обычно умеет сам автоматически всё сжимать в gzip или brotli. Какой у вас веб-сервер и как он настроен?

Comment: @andreymal пока никакой, работаю на локальном. Тоесть если будет gzip то все данные будут передоваться в сжатом виде? А где можно это проследить то что они в сжатом? Это будет видно в вебтулсе во вкладке network? Там я смотрю какие данные передаются и их размер

Comment: Веб-сервер указывает Content-Encoding в заголовках ответа; если его нет, значит не сжато. В крайнем случае вы можете сжать вручную и добавить Content-Encoding тоже вручную через php, но наверное лучше этого не делать, если веб-сервер сам поддерживает сжатие

Answer (score 0):

Может помочь добавление в файл .htaccess строк:

```
# сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml, json:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css application/json text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```